# What is the official name for this algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have two HTML elements both with `data-final-figure` attribute on them. Either one of those `final figure` on the elements can be assigned a value or be left empty, but can NOT be set in conflict with each other. Now I'm using a quite inefficient way to:
1) check if the first one is `null`, if it's not `null`, then put it into a variable;
2) then check if the second one is`null`, if it's not, and the first one is `null`, then copy it back to the first `data-final-figure` attr; if it's not `null` and the first one is not `null` either, then check if they are assigned an identical value, if not, then they are conflicting and here we throw an error because both elements are specified a different value. If the second is `null` and the first one is not, then copy the first one's value to the second.

I dimly remember this algorithm in one of the textbook but can't put my finger on the name. It's not Hanoi tower I'm sure. Is there a better way to implement? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Why not just `if (val1 && val2 && val1 == val2) { report error }`

Comment: Why are you copying values from one to the other when one of them is null? Won't that create a conflict?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  A conflict is when they're different, I thought it was if they were the same.

Comment: I don't recognize this as a common programming pattern, I don't think it's common enough to have a name.

Comment: Note that attribute values are strings; when the attribute exists, it cannot have a `null` value. If absent it would be `undefined`. If "empty", it's value is the empty string.

Comment: re trincot's comment, note that `undefined == null` returns `true`. (But `undefined === null` returns `false`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm can be simplified. Here's pseudo-code:

```
var1 = elem1.attribute
var2 = elem2.attribute
if (var1 && var2 && var1 != var2) {
    report conflict
} else if (!var1 || !var2) { // one is null
    value = var1 || var2; // Get the non-null value
    var1.attribute = var2.attribute = value // Assign it to both
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, what if we have 10 elements to compare instead of 2? How do you see this algorithm scale from 2 to 10?

Comment: Use a loop to test if all the values are the same or null, and get the first non-null value into a variable. Then another loop can assign the variable to all the null entries.

Comment: Also, I'm a little struggling to understand your `else if` part, why do you need to check `!var1 || !var2`? I think once the code executes to that point it should go ahead to sync the value no matter what. Is there really a justifiable reason for that `else if`?

Comment: If the condition is false, they're both already set to the same value, so there's no need to set them again.

Comment: by the way, I think this comparison deserves a name, how about calling it `Barmar sync method`?